# Authentication of JIRA APIs in Python?

Tags: python, confluence

I'm trying to authenticate a [JIRA REST API](https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/latest/). Using HTTP basic auth gives me 401 response.

Can some one please suggest a best way to make a HTTP get call using REST API.

The Python utility for making a http request is:

```
def download(url, destination):
    request = urllib2.Request(url)

    print "Downloading: " + url
    print "Save to: " + destination

    if os.path.isfile(destination):
        print 'File already existed'
        return destination

    username = raw_input('Enter username for download (blank for no auth): ')
    if username:
        password = getpass.getpass('Enter password for download: ')
        base64string = base64.encodestring('%s:%s' % (username,password)).replace('\n', '')
        request.add_header("Authorization", "Basic %s" % base64string)
        print 'Auth entered'
    else:
        print 'No auth entered'

    # Open the url
    success = False
    try:
        print 'Downloading...'
        response = urllib2.urlopen(request)

        # Open our local file for writing
        with open(destination, "wb") as local_file:
            _chunkRead(response, local_file)
            success = True
        print 'Done'
        return destination

    #handle errors
    except urllib2.HTTPError, e:
        print "HTTP Error: ", e.code, url, e
    except urllib2.URLError, e:
        print "URL Error: ", e.reason, url, e
    finally:
        if not success:
            print 'Cleaning up file: ', destination
            os.remove(destination)

    return None
```

And a typical JIRA url would be: https://issues.labcollab.net/browse/SOMEPROJ-123

Comment: `http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/` python-requests is a great library to make http requests. It would be better if you could include your code for better understanding.

Comment: I used oauth authentication for a project recently. It was very simple. This tutorial on Atlassian's documentation was pretty helpful. Specifically see the python example source code. https://bitbucket.org/atlassian_tutorial/atlassian-oauth-examples/src

Comment: Awesome. Atlassian's example helped.

Answer (score 0):

I used this function to build the authentication string in basic authentication and worked like a charm:

```python
import base64

def get_auth_code(user, password):
    auth_code = user + ':' + password
    auth_code = base64.b64encode(bytes(auth_code, 'utf-8'))
    auth_code = auth_code.decode('ascii')
    return auth_code
```